# Objective C, Core Data Fetch Request

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am updating an app to included a toolbar item that totals items. My fetch request is generating an error.

```
NSArray *resultsArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

The error is: Incompatible pointer types initialising 'NSArray *' with an expression of type '_kindof NSPersistentStoreResult* _Nullable'

I believe I saw something about Objective C updates that deals with Nullable but cannot work out how to modify the NSArray statement.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the nullability updates-- it's that you're calling the new-ish `executeRequest:error:` when it looks like you want to call `executeFetchRequest:error:`

Comment: Thank you, I imagined it was staring me in the face, now it works as it should, with no crashes etc.